# dragging a group with snapsvg

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

I'd like to **drag a group** with **snapsvg**.
The Group should only be dragable on the x-axis.
So fare i build this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var were = function() {
        var that = this;
        this.wer = Snap("100%", 500);
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.group = this.wer.g();

        this.construct = function() {
            for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                that.one(i - 1, 0);
            }

            that.group.drag(
                function (dx, dy, x, y, e) {
                    this.attr({
                        x: Snap.snapTo(20, that.x + dx, 100000000),
                        y: 0
                    });
                },

                function (x, y, e) {
                    that.x = e.toElement.x.baseVal.value;
                    that.y = e.toElement.y.baseVal.value;
                }
            );
        };

        this.one = function(x, y) {
            this.width = 19;
            this.height = 60;

            that.group.add(that.wer.rect(x * (this.width + 1), y, this.width, this.height).attr({
                "fill": "#CCC"
            }));
        }
    }

    var test = new were();
    test.construct();
}
```

But it doesnt work so fare.

If i apply the same drag function on only one element instedt of the group, it works. It also works if i remove the functions within the drag function. But i dont see the mistake.

Comment: Here i edited an example of someone else. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4wMUy/19/) Here you can also so, that this code works with an single element. But as fare as i put the element into a group and try to apply the same function it doesnt work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is groups are a container object, and have no x,y attributes. They will essentially be the sum of their elements, and you move these with a transform.

The basic principles are similar. You store the starting transform, and adjust a translation relative to that. You can set it so that vertical translation isn't changed.

Using the fiddle jStiller provided, you can come up with an example like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54W3w/7/)

```
var s = Snap("#svg");

var block = s.rect(150, 0, 100, 100, 20, 20).attr({
  fill: "rgb(236, 240, 241)",
  stroke: "#1f2c39",
  strokeWidth: 3
});

var block2 = block.clone().transform('t0,100');
var group = s.g(block, block2);

group.drag(
  function (dx, dy, x, y, e) {  
    var tdx = +this.data('ot').split().dx + dx;

    var newTx = Snap.snapTo(50, tdx, 100000000)
    this.attr({
      transform: 't' + [newTx, 0]  
    });
  },
  function (x, y, e) {
     this.data('ot', this.transform().localMatrix);
});
```

Comment: There was a nasty bug in this, so redid the drag function.